# "В кокосе содержится/атся: ..." Единственное или множественное число?

Tags: единственное-множественное-число

"В кокосе содержится/атся:

- витамины B1, B2, B5, C;
- микроэлементы...". Нужно ли ставить глагол во множественном числе?

Comment: Уточните вопрос, дополнив примером хотя бы одной строки перечьня.

Comment: Уже добавила...

Comment: И все же здесь нужно мн.ч., так форма подлежащего в мн.ч стоит.

Comment: Неоднозначно: кокос-то один.

Comment: Микроэлементы, витамины  содержатся в кокосе.

Comment: Думается, автор так представляет: всё это содержит один кокос. А до других дела нету.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кокос, конечно же, один (главным членом, правда, не является).
Но ведь и первое, и второе подлежащее имеют **множественное** число: *витамины содерж**а**тся, микроэлементы содерж**а**тся*.
Откуда же тут единственному-то числу взяться?

*В кокосе содержатся:

• витамины B1, B2, B5, C;

• микроэлементы...*

Из статей:
*Она полезна, в ней содержатся витамины и микроэлементы;

В нем содержатся витамины и микроэлементы, необходимые человеку;

Помимо того, что дыня способствует стабилизации водного баланса, в ее составе содержатся витамины и микроэлементы...*

Единственное число будет вот здесь (кокос — подлежащее):
*Кокос содержит:

• витамины B1, B2, B5, C;

• микроэлементы...*